# Closing tags formatting in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: regex, macros, intellij-idea, coldfusion, code-formatting

Help needed to set-up a macro/code-formatting/code-style/reformat code where in the code I write (Coldfusion), is tag based and the ending of a tag needs to be formatted.

The CFML code formatter is not doing this. All I want is when I format my code, any tag that is closed or ends with `/>` without a space from its previous character(any character), needs to be spaced and closed.

Example: any code line that ends with `)/>` or `"/>` or `character/>` `capital-letter/>` or `digit/>` or `anything/>` needs to be changed to `) />` or `" />` or `character />` `capital letter />` or `digit />` or `anything />` respectively.

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to configure the IntelliJ formatter to do this. You need to use Find | Replace in Path... with a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks yole for the response and I have already tried to "Find/Replace" with regular expression. I am able to figure out the "Find" part of regular expression to match my requirement to this [A-Za-z0-9)"']\/> but, not able to come up with the "Replace" part of the regular expression. So, wondering if you could help me build the "Replace" regular expression to achieve this.

Comment: Put the part before /> in a group and use $1 to refer to the contents of that group in the replacement regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an automatic conversion for `<empty-tag/>` to `<empty-tag />`, you can do that in IntelliJ preferences: Editor->Code Style->XML. Open "Other" and under "Spaces" section on the left check "In empty tag".